# ¿Como llamar un elemento de un objeto en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, component

Mi duda es particular, no he podido hacer el llamado a un elemento en especial de un objeto que tengo en un archivo en js

https://gitlab.com/folayao/react-coursera-felipe/-/tree/master/src/component

**ARCHIVO Con el OBJETO**

```
export const DISHES =
    [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }, ...
```

En éste hay mas objetos obviamente identificados con una id, la idea es que quiero poner los comentarios en un card, pero no me renderea el contenido que esta dentro de este objeto y no tengo muy claro como hacer el llamado a este, el archivo se llama **dishes.js** y se encuentra en la carpeta **src/shared**

Este componente que es un card, está aparte del componente que lo va renderear

**Componente Card llamado DishDetailComponent**

```
/* Modules */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardText, CardBody } from 'reactstrap';

class DishDetailComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {

        }
    }

    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
    }

    renderComments(dish) {
        if (dish != null) {
            return (
                <Card >
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardText>{dish.comments}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row ml-1">
                {this.renderComments(this.state.onDishSelect)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DishDetailComponent;
```

** Componente que renderea el Card Anterior llamado MenuComponent **

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

/* Components */
import DishDetail from './DishDetailComponent'

class MenuComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null
        };
        console.log('Menu Component constructor is invoked');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Menu Component componentDidMount is invoked')
    }

    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dish }); /* Remember, read the code, 
        do not do an equals use the setState 
        to say what do you want to change on
        this.state, in this case, we say to change the null state of
        selectedDish (selectedDish:null) to something like 
        (selectedDish: dish) This is too important to understand how it works */
    }

    renderDish(dish) {
        if (dish != null) {
            return (
                <Card >
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => { /* This is a prop that are provided from App.js 
            in the render() <MenuComponent dishes={}> */
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                        <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        <CardImgOverlay>
                            <CardTitle><strong>{dish.name}</strong></CardTitle>
                        </CardImgOverlay>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            );
        });



        console.log('Menu component render is invoked')

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
                <div className="row col-12 col-lg-12 my-1 mr-1">
                    <div>
                        <Card className="">
                            {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)}
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Card>
                            <DishDetail />
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MenuComponent;
```

Si quieren mirar el resto de archivos aca adjunto mi GIT!

https://gitlab.com/folayao/react-coursera-felipe/-/tree/master/src/component

Comment: El problema es que estás pasando a CardText el objeto comments, cuando lo que podrías hacer es aplicar un map al array de comentarios y devolver así una lista de componentes que muestren cada comentario. Algo tipo `comments.map (comment => <CommentDetail {...comment}/>)`